# Tensorflow API OD only able to train 2 cycles and then is stalled

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm fine tuning CNN models from the Tensorflow API OD in Google Colab but then after training 2 cycles, the training process stalled. Here is the last traceback:

````
Use fn_output_signature instead
INFO:tensorflow:Step 100 per-step time 24.890s
I0512 15:24:21.516056 140628079740800 model_lib_v2.py:707] Step 100 per-step time 24.890s
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 0.5017479,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.43371227,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.2621385,
 'Loss/total_loss': 1.1975987,
 'learning_rate': 0.014666351}
I0512 15:24:21.522881 140628079740800 model_lib_v2.py:708] {'Loss/classification_loss': 0.5017479,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.43371227,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.2621385,
 'Loss/total_loss': 1.1975987,
 'learning_rate': 0.014666351}
INFO:tensorflow:Step 200 per-step time 24.871s
I0512 16:05:48.604570 140628079740800 model_lib_v2.py:707] Step 200 per-step time 24.871s
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/classification_loss': 0.32925454,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.17537248,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.26339543,
 'Loss/total_loss': 0.7680224,
 'learning_rate': 0.0159997}
I0512 16:05:48.605150 140628079740800 model_lib_v2.py:708] {'Loss/classification_loss': 0.32925454,
 'Loss/localization_loss': 0.17537248,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.26339543,
 'Loss/total_loss': 0.7680224,
 'learning_rate': 0.0159997}```

What I can do to solve this issue, I already reduced batch size to 2 and step to 2000.
````

Comment: post your training script

Comment: Post the pipeline.config